# AttributeError when serializing model object on deletion

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-serializer

I work an a django project and want to keep objects deleted by users for databases synchronization, so I decided to store them in a json file. For this I override the delete() method of the model. 
I first retreive previously deleted objects from the file, and then add the one being deleted. When serializing this new list, I get an AttributeError:

> AttributeError: 'DeserializedObject' object has no attribute '_meta'

What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the delete() code :

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    force = kwargs.pop("force", None)

    if force is None:
        objects_to_delete = list()
        user_dir_path = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, self.user.username)
        if not os.path.exists(user_dir_path):
            os.makedirs(user_dir_path)
        path = os.path.join(user_dir_path, "obj_to_delete.json")
        if os.path.exists(path):
            with open(path, "r") as fp:
                json_str = fp.read()
                if len(json_str) > 0:
                    objects_to_delete = list(serializers.deserialize(
                        "json",
                        json_str,
                        indent=4,
                        use_natural_foreign_keys=True, 
                        fields=('pk', 'user', 'slug')
                        ))

        objects_to_delete.append(self)

        if objects_to_delete:
            with open(path, "w") as fp:
                jsonData = serializers.serialize("json", 
                    objects_to_delete, indent=4, 
                    use_natural_foreign_keys=True, 
                    fields=('pk', 'user', 'slug')
                )
                fp.write(jsonData)

    super(UserOwnedModel,self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data

As stated in the documentation, the deserialize method from the serializers doesn't return your object directly but rather wrap it in a DeserializeObject. You need to call deserialized_object.object for instance to access your object.

You can try this instead:

```
objects_to_delete = list(obj.object for obj in serializers.deserialize(
    "json",
    json_str,
    indent=4,
    use_natural_foreign_keys=True, 
    fields=('pk', 'user', 'slug')
    ))
```